# Webcrawling script producing different results on two different machines

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, web-crawler

I created a webcrawler in Python using BeautifulSoup's API. The webcrawler uses the same header information/user-agent when crawling certain sites.I notice that when I run the same exact script (one on my laptop and another on a server) on two different machines to crawl a given site, they produce different results. By "different results," I mean that the script ran on the server does not crawl to all the links on  the site.

For example, if I wanted to crawl Macys.com, the script on my laptop would crawl to each department(home, bedbath, womens,mens,etc.) while the script running on the server would miss bedbath department. This is really confusing me since they both use the same script with the same header information/user-agent to crawl the same site. I cannot think of any other setting that could be causing this

Here is how I am defining my user-agent in python and creating a soup object

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7"
hdr={'User-Agent':user_agent} 
response = urlopen(Request(current_url, headers=hdr))
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Comment: And do you always explicitly specify the parser (in this case `lxml`)? Do you have `lxml` installed both locally and on the server? Thanks.

Comment: Is the html that you get on both machines the same?

Comment: @Isaac, no the html is indeed different

Comment: @alecxe, during the comparison, i left both scripts to use the default html parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the parser explicitly, `BeautifulSoup` [will pick up the underlying parser automatically](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

The problem here is that it chooses different parsers locally and on the server depending on the modules that are available/installed in the python environment. And, since there are [differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers), you see different results.

Explicitly specify the parser, that fits your needs, for example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Comment: so if I am understanding this correctly, when I did not specify an explicit parser to use, the script running on the server is possibly using a different parser than the one on my laptop?

Comment: @lollerskates this is exactly what I'm trying to explain. Please check.

Comment: hey alec I checked the parser that is being user by the script running on the server. And it is running 'html.parser' which is why different result were being produced. Thanks!